# how to convert a unix date like 20140222T08:27:11 to Date() in java

Tags: java

I am to convert this date 20140222T08:27:11 into a Date object in java.
Since, it is containing a character "T" thats why i am having a problem in conversion.
Help!

Comment: Well what have you tried? You probably want SimpleDateFormat - or better yet, use Joda Time...

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date date = df.parse(text);
```